# How to call the search bar from home page of my website onto the 'Latest Products' page and other pages?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Home page URL: http://www.ashvinrx.com/magento/index.php/ 
latest products page URL: http://www.ashvinrx.com/magento/index.php/newproducts

Comment: Please add more meaningful information about the problem and the steps taken to solve it.

Comment: I have a website in magento. You can see it here http://www.ashvinrx.com/magento/index.php/

Comment: I want to add/call the search bar which is currently on the home page, to this page http://www.ashvinrx.com/magento/index.php/newproducts .